# Why my previous commands won't work in my linux distro in WSL 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, windows-10, debian, wsl-2

had this issue wherein I have to install wsl2 to my windows 10 computer and install debian as my distro since I had some issues with installing rails,
specifically

```
error: mingw32: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: mingw64: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: msys: signature from "David Macek <david.macek.0@gmail.com>" is unknown trust
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'mingw64' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'msys' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    current directory: C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20220204-7536-686k2k.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

someone suggested installing wsl2 and I've replaced ubuntu with debian
but when I run debian in win-10 terminal, commands won't work such as

```
$ rails
-bash: /mnt/e/Ruby27-x64/bin/rails: E:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The relevant part of this error is `sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.`

Comment: just installed WSL2 on my win10 computer.